# probability subspaces that make entropy function equal to a constant value

Tags: calculus, inverse, entropy, elementary-functions

Given the entropy fucntion:

$$ H = -\sum_i^n p(i) \ln(p(i))\,.$$

where $p(i)$ are probabilities and $n=4$, I would like to know all the points in the probability space that make $H = k$, being $k$ a given constant.
I've done some numeric aproximations, but I would like to know if the solution can be expressed as an elementary function. If it doesn't exist, where could I find the proof?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "What are the level sets of $H$, as a function of the $n$-tuple $(p(i))_{i=1}^n$?" is a more efficient way to put it, and more likely, I think to be immediately understood by most mathematicians.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I thought that near the point $(\frac1n,\ldots,\frac1n)$, the level sets would be nearly spheres centered at that point.  But now I realize I don't know any reason why that should be so.

Comment: The level curves are egg-shaped, at least when n=4

Comment: But does the shape approach some particular limit as the center, $(\frac1n,\ldots,\frac1n)$, is approached?

Comment: The center is the point that maximize the entropy H. As the center is approached, the shape is lost and any point in a square arround the center gives the same constant entropy
Does it give you any clue? I couldn't find bibliography about it, probably because I don't know where to search. It surprised me not to find any data, though, because it seems to be a question that somebody surely encountered before